# ssh works on bash but does not work when I use zsh or other terminal, killed on preauth

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh

Recently I have this problem that when I try to log in into a remote box using ssh from a terminal with bash, it connects successfully most of the time. The command I use is just

```
ssh -vvvv -p PORT USER@IP
```

Sometimes (very seldomly) I get the following error

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/USER/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname IP is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port PORT.
debug1: connect to address IP port PORT: Unknown error: -536870212
ssh: connect to host IP port PORT: Unknown error: -536870212
```

BUT, I get that error almost ALL the time if I change to zsh (or fish). I have to actually put the ssh command inside a while loop until it is successful. What could be the root cause to this? I have incremented MaxSessions and MaxStartups on the server side. The log files only say te client disconnected on preauth. Can it be that some env vars are affecting locally ssh? Do you have any idea on how to track this and fix it? thank you

Edit: Thanks to @pynexj comment and according to https://communities.apple.com/de/thread/251124631 I had to update openssh. The default version in Mojave is

```
/usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

and after installing a new version with brew the problem was solved

```
brew install openssh
/usr/local/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

The ssh connection now works in bash, zsh, fish, etc. So the solution was the usual : update it. Thanks

Comment: may be caused by some env vars which are different between your shells? could you try `env -i ssh -vvv ...`?

Comment: Is your $PATH the same? Are you using the same ssh executable in zsh that you use in bash?

Comment: @glennjackman yes, it is, and yes, I am using exactly the same one, which ssh shows /usr/bin/ssh on both shells.

Comment: @pynexj it is curious. The command env -i ssh -p PORT USER@IP started failing more with the same error in bash! mostly as bad as in zsh. From reading env manual -i means use an empty env. What could that important var that is generating the error?

Comment: had a look at openssh code and the error "Unknown error: -536870212" is from [strerror(errno)](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_9_P1/sshconnect.c#L554). seems like something very weird happening. what OS are you using? did you install openssh by yourself?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detective work. I am using locally mac os x mojave, remotely slackware -current. No, I did not installed openssh from source, I would not dare. ssh from other machines to the server works without problems

Comment: found the same error reported on catalina with the same openssh and libressl version here: https://communities.apple.com/de/thread/251124631 . i'd suggest you also try a new openssh.

Comment: Hi @Pynex, thanks a lot, that solved it. The old version was
    OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
And now I haves installed with brew
    OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
and it works. Thanks

Comment: That's great that your problem got solved! However, you should _not_ mark that with [SOLVED] in the title; that's not how we do things around here. Instead, either A) close your question or B) post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pynexj, I just had to upgrade my openssh version to fix the problem. First, I had

```
$ /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
```

Then, after running

```
brew install openssh
```

I got the updated version

```
$ /usr/local/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

and ssh works on any shell